# Missing all BOOST_* macros on Debian 10

Tags: c++, boost

I installed `libboost-all-dev` (v1.67) on my fully up-to-date Debian 10 machine to work with a closed-source source-tree we licensed of a different company. It won't compile due to many boost-related issues. I was able to narrow it down to the lack of nearly all `BOOST_*` macros.

Then I created a minimal test

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>  //every boost-functionality uses this include
#ifndef BOOST_NOEXCEPT
#error MISSING BOOST_NOEXCEPT!
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

When running `g++ boost_test.cpp -o boost_test && ./boost_test` the compilation fails with

```
boost_test.cpp:3:2: error: #error MISSING BOOST_NOEXCEPT!
 #error MISSING BOOST_NOEXCEPT!
```

This puzzles me since [the doc clearly states](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_allow_use_of_c__11_features_with_c__03_compilers) that, no matter what, `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` should be defined:

> If `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT` is defined (i.e. C++03 compliant compilers) these macros are defined as:
>
> ```
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_OR_NOTHROW throw()
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF(Predicate)
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(Expression) false
> ```
>
> If `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT` is not defined (i.e. C++11 compliant compilers) they are defined as:
>
> ```
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT noexcept
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_OR_NOTHROW noexcept
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF(Predicate) noexcept((Predicate))
>    #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(Expression) noexcept((Expression))
> ```

However, when manually including `boost/config/detail/suffix.hpp` (where `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` gets defined) it is correctly defined. Now I don't know what's wrong because `<boost/config.hpp>` already does include `suffix.hpp`.

Is something wrong with my installation? I don't want to manually hot-fix this by including `boost/config/detail/suffix.hpp` in every boost-related file in the source-tree.

Comment: can't reproduce with a clean debian 10 docker image, I guess your headers have been corrupted somehow, try re-installing boost

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for checking! It comforts me, that the Debian10 headers itself are ok, but it bugs me that they aren't on my machine. I'll try it myself in docker then.